# ORMLite Join Queries with Query Builder

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm having some issue with understanding join queries in ormlite.
ormlite query builder supports 4 join methods.

```
1. join()
2. joinOr();
3. leftJoin();
4. leftJoinOr();
```

I can understand join() following picture illustrates join() method.

[image]

Please explain me other join methods using similar pictures?

(I can understand other join types in generic SQL, but when it comes to ORMLite query builder methods are different it seems)

Pictures taken from [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please explain me other join methods using similar pictures?

I've spent a lot of time on the javadocs.  They should be helpful.  They explain what SQL is being used and that the "Or" part is.

1. `join()` is the same as a SQL `INNER JOIN` as [stated in the javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#join%28com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29).  That matches your picture.
2. `joinOr()` is the same as a SQL `INNER JOIN` but the `WHERE` parts of the two queries are "OR'd" together as [stated in the javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#joinOr%28com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29).  Same picture as #1.
3. `leftJoin()` is the same as (wait for it) a SQL `LEFT JOIN` as [stated in the javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#leftJoin%28com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29).  That corresponds to adding A to the area in red.  See your [linked post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) and look for `LEFT JOIN`.
4. `leftJoinOr()` is the same as a SQL `LEFT JOIN` as well but the `WHERE` parts of the two queries are "OR'd" together as [stated in the javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#leftJoinOr%28com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29).  Same picture as #3.

Comment: Thanks @Gray for the answer, definitely your javadocs are really helpful, just wanted some pictorial clarification due to lack of SQL knowledge. Really appreciate your contribution to the community by introducing the best ORM tool for Android.