# Can you do multi join queries with ormlite?

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a relatively complex model and want to do a query with a multi table join to query a field. I have 2 tables I need to join with 1 in between. The only examples I have seen join 2 tables so have the parent and query the child.

Can this be done or can I apply a custom query I write by hand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORMLite Join Queries with Query Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213173/ormlite-join-queries-with-query-builder)

Comment: That covers singletons, can't find examples with multi levels of joins and criteria on the furthest table